Quotient of decreasing bounded sequences is definely increasing
Suppose that $\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers with $a_k\in[0,1]$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $a_k$ is decreasing ($a_k > a_{k+1})$ and that $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$.
Question
Prove or disprove that the sequence $b_k = \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}< 1$ is increasing $\forall k\geq k_0$.
Examples
Sequences which satisfy the condition are for example $\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}},\frac{1}{k^2},\frac{1}{\log{k+1}},...$. Note that $b_k$ is increasing if and only if:
$$
(a_k)^2\leq a_{k-1}a_{k+1}
$$
just by manipulating $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}} \geq \frac{a_{k}}{a_{k-1}}$.
Update
As pointed out there are counterexamples. But what could be a condition that $a_k$ should satisfy such that $b_k$ is increasing?

There's no reason for this to be true. Indeed, setting $a_k = 1/k!$ we see that $b_k = 1/(k+1)$ decreases.

Totally true. What could be a condition such that $b_k$ is an incresing sequence like in the examples I gave? Maybe that $b_k\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$..?
